# ExtJS5: Custom theme for tabpanel

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have created a custom theme for my application. The base color of the theme is white. I have a tabpanel on one of my view. There are almost 15 tabs on that view. Not all the tabs can be visible at the same time therefore scrollers are added by default for navigation between tabs at left and right. The issue is the color of the scrollers. With neptune or any other default theme these scrollers are clearly visible but with the custom theme they are plain white. User can't even know that there are srollers there. The scroller image is also not visible. Can someone specify the SAAS variables that configures the scroller appearance? $panel-tool-background-image: 'tools/tool-sprites' or $panel-tool-background-image: 'tools/tool-sprites-dark' do not work either.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation should provide what you need ("CSS Variables" section). There are a few relating to the scroller.

http://ext5-docs.site/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel

You could also look at using the `extjs-tab-panel-ui` mixin to create a custom `ui` for your tab panel:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/theming.html#Creating_Custom_Component_UIs